# Android implementing tabbed layout that you can swipe across

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to implement a layout that looks like a tabbed view, but is it possible to implement it in such a way that if the user swipes horizontally, then it will switch to a different tab? A good example of this is the Google+ app for Android. In the streams Activity, there are three tabs (or subsections): Nearby, All Circles, and Incoming. Notice how when you swipe in one horizontal direction, the screen scrolls to the corresponding subsection. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with fragments and viewpager. you can use the things through android-support-v4 library. android-support-v4 library including the example matches your need.